# How to define Cross Validation with Different Criteria in LIBSVM?

Tags: c++, libsvm

I'm using LIBSVM for a ML project and I would like to have as output in cross validation mode (**-v option**)multiple evaluation function like precision, recall, fscore etc.

Actually I was following this [guide](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/eval/index.html). I made the changes but when I'm compiling I'm having errors like `eval.cpp:32:10: error: redefinition of 'validation_function' double (*validation_function)(const dvec_t&, const ivec_t&) = recall`

Here the entire eval.cpp script

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <errno.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "svm.h"
#include "eval.h"

#define Malloc(type,n) (type *)malloc((n)*sizeof(type))


typedef std::vector<double> dvec_t;
typedef std::vector<int> ivec_t;

// prototypes of evaluation functions
double precision(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty);
double recall(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty);
double fscore(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty);
double bac(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty);
double auc(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty);
double accuracy(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty);
double ap(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty);


// evaluation function pointer
//double eval_func(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty);

// You can assign this pointer to any above prototype

double (*validation_function)(const dvec_t&, const ivec_t&) = accuracy;
double (*validation_function)(const dvec_t&, const ivec_t&) = precision;
double (*validation_function)(const dvec_t&, const ivec_t&) = recall;

static char *line = NULL;
static int max_line_len;


static char* readline(FILE *input)
{
    int len;

    if(fgets(line,max_line_len,input) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    while(strrchr(line,'\n') == NULL)
    {
        max_line_len *= 2;
        line = (char *) realloc(line,max_line_len);
        len = (int) strlen(line);
        if(fgets(line+len,max_line_len-len,input) == NULL)
            break;
    }
    return line;
}



double precision(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty){
    size_t size = dec_values.size();
    size_t i;
    int    tp, fp;
    double precision;

    tp = fp = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) if(dec_values[i] >= 0){
        if(ty[i] == 1) ++tp;
        else           ++fp;
    }

    if(tp + fp == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "warning: No positive predict label.\n");
        precision = 0;
    }else
        precision = tp / (double) (tp + fp);
    printf("Precision = %g%% (%d/%d)\n", 100.0 * precision, tp, tp + fp);

    return precision;
}



double recall(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty){
        size_t size = dec_values.size();
        size_t i;
        int    tp, fn; // true_positive and false negative
        double recall;

        tp = fn = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) if(ty[i] == 1){ // true label is 1
            if(dec_values[i] >= 0) ++tp; // predict label is 1
            else                   ++fn; // predict label is -1
        }

        recall = tp / (double) (tp + fn);

        // print result in case of  invocation in prediction
        printf("Recall = %g%%\n", 100.0 * recall);

        return recall; // return the evaluation value
    }



double fscore(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty){
    size_t size = dec_values.size();
    size_t i;
    int    tp, fp, fn;
    double precision, recall;
    double fscore;

    tp = fp = fn = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
        if(dec_values[i] >= 0 && ty[i] == 1) ++tp;
        else if(dec_values[i] >= 0 && ty[i] == -1) ++fp;
        else if(dec_values[i] <  0 && ty[i] == 1) ++fn;

    if(tp + fp == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "warning: No postive predict label.\n");
        precision = 0;
    }else
        precision = tp / (double) (tp + fp);
    if(tp + fn == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "warning: No postive true label.\n");
        recall = 0;
    }else
        recall = tp / (double) (tp + fn);


    if(precision + recall == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "warning: precision + recall = 0.\n");
        fscore = 0;
    }else
        fscore = 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall);

    printf("F-score = %g\n", fscore);

    return fscore;
}



double bac(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty){
    size_t size = dec_values.size();
    size_t i;
    int    tp, fp, fn, tn;
    double specificity, recall;
    double bac;

    tp = fp = fn = tn = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
        if(dec_values[i] >= 0 && ty[i] == 1) ++tp;
        else if(dec_values[i] >= 0 && ty[i] == -1) ++fp;
        else if(dec_values[i] <  0 && ty[i] == 1)  ++fn;
        else ++tn;

    if(tn + fp == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "warning: No negative true label.\n");
        specificity = 0;
    }else
        specificity = tn / (double)(tn + fp);
    if(tp + fn == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "warning: No positive true label.\n");
        recall = 0;
    }else
        recall = tp / (double)(tp + fn);

    bac = (specificity + recall) / 2;
    printf("BAC = %g\n", bac);

    return bac;
}



// for auc and ap
class Comp{
    const double *dec_val;
    public:
    Comp(const double *ptr): dec_val(ptr){}
    bool operator()(int i, int j) const{
        return dec_val[i] > dec_val[j];
    }
};


double auc(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty){
    double roc  = 0;
    size_t size = dec_values.size();
    size_t i;
    std::vector<size_t> indices(size);

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) indices[i] = i;

    std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), Comp(&dec_values[0]));

    int tp = 0,fp = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(ty[indices[i]] == 1) tp++;
        else if(ty[indices[i]] == -1) {
            roc += tp;
            fp++;
        }
    }

    if(tp == 0 || fp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "warning: Too few postive true labels or negative true labels\n");
        roc = 0;
    }
    else
        roc = roc / tp / fp;

    printf("AUC = %g\n", roc);

    return roc;
}



double accuracy(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty){
    int    correct = 0;
    int    total   = (int) ty.size();
    size_t i;

    for(i = 0; i < ty.size(); ++i)
        if(ty[i] == (dec_values[i] >= 0? 1: -1)) ++correct;

    printf("Accuracy = %g%% (%d/%d)\n",
        (double)correct/total*100,correct,total);

    return (double) correct / total;
}



double ap(const dvec_t& dec_values, const ivec_t& ty){
    size_t size = dec_values.size();
    size_t i;
    std::vector<size_t> indices(size);

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) indices[i] = i;
    std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), Comp(&dec_values[0]));

    int p = 0, tp = 0;
    double prev_recall = 0, area = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) p += (ty[i] == 1);

    if(p == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "warning: Too few postive labels\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        tp += (ty[indices[i]] == 1);

        if(i+1 < size && dec_values[indices[i]] == dec_values[indices[i+1]]) 
            continue;

        double recall = (double)tp/p;
        double precision = (double)tp/(double)(i+1);

        area += precision*(recall-prev_recall);
        prev_recall = recall;
    }

    printf("AP = %g\n", area);
    return area;
}



double binary_class_cross_validation(const svm_problem *prob, const svm_parameter *param, int nr_fold)
{
    int i;
    int *fold_start = Malloc(int,nr_fold+1);
    int l = prob->l;
    int *perm = Malloc(int,l);
    int *labels;
    dvec_t dec_values;
    ivec_t ty;

    for(i=0;i<l;i++) perm[i]=i;
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        int j = i+rand()%(l-i);
        std::swap(perm[i],perm[j]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<=nr_fold;i++)
        fold_start[i]=i*l/nr_fold;

    for(i=0;i<nr_fold;i++)
    {
        int                begin   = fold_start[i];
        int                end     = fold_start[i+1];
        int                j,k;
        struct svm_problem subprob;

        subprob.l = l-(end-begin);
        subprob.x = Malloc(struct svm_node*,subprob.l);
        subprob.y = Malloc(double,subprob.l);

        k=0;
        for(j=0;j<begin;j++)
        {
            subprob.x[k] = prob->x[perm[j]];
            subprob.y[k] = prob->y[perm[j]];
            ++k;
        }
        for(j=end;j<l;j++)
        {
            subprob.x[k] = prob->x[perm[j]];
            subprob.y[k] = prob->y[perm[j]];
            ++k;
        }
        struct svm_model *submodel = svm_train(&subprob,param);
        int svm_type = svm_get_svm_type(submodel);

        if(svm_type == NU_SVR || svm_type == EPSILON_SVR){
            fprintf(stderr, "wrong svm type");
            exit(1);
        }

        labels = Malloc(int, svm_get_nr_class(submodel));
        svm_get_labels(submodel, labels);

        if(svm_get_nr_class(submodel) > 2) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Error: the number of class is not equal to 2\n");
            exit(-1);
        }

        dec_values.resize(end);
        ty.resize(end);

        for(j=begin;j<end;j++) {
            svm_predict_values(submodel,prob->x[perm[j]], &dec_values[j]);
            ty[j] = (prob->y[perm[j]] > 0)? 1: -1;
        }


        if(labels[0] <= 0) {
            for(j=begin;j<end;j++)
                dec_values[j] *= -1;
        }

        svm_free_and_destroy_model(&submodel);
        free(subprob.x);
        free(subprob.y);
        free(labels);
    }       

    free(perm);
    free(fold_start);

    return validation_function(dec_values, ty); 
}


void binary_class_predict(FILE *input, FILE *output){
    int    total = 0;
    int    *labels;
    int    max_nr_attr = 64;
    struct svm_node *x = Malloc(struct svm_node, max_nr_attr);
    dvec_t dec_values;
    ivec_t true_labels;


    int svm_type=svm_get_svm_type(model);

    if (svm_type==NU_SVR || svm_type==EPSILON_SVR){
        fprintf(stderr, "wrong svm type.");
        exit(1);
    }

    labels = Malloc(int, svm_get_nr_class(model));
    svm_get_labels(model, labels);


    max_line_len = 1024;
    line = (char *)malloc(max_line_len*sizeof(char));
    while(readline(input) != NULL)
    {
        int i = 0;
        double target_label, predict_label;
        char *idx, *val, *label, *endptr;
        int inst_max_index = -1; // strtol gives 0 if wrong format, and precomputed kernel has <index> start from 0

        label = strtok(line," \t");
        target_label = strtod(label,&endptr);
        if(endptr == label)
            exit_input_error(total+1);

        while(1)
        {
            if(i>=max_nr_attr - 2)  // need one more for index = -1
            {
                max_nr_attr *= 2;
                x = (struct svm_node *) realloc(x,max_nr_attr*sizeof(struct svm_node));
            }

            idx = strtok(NULL,":");
            val = strtok(NULL," \t");

            if(val == NULL)
                break;
            errno = 0;
            x[i].index = (int) strtol(idx,&endptr,10);
            if(endptr == idx || errno != 0 || *endptr != '\0' || x[i].index <= inst_max_index)
                exit_input_error(total+1);
            else
                inst_max_index = x[i].index;

            errno = 0;
            x[i].value = strtod(val,&endptr);
            if(endptr == val || errno != 0 || (*endptr != '\0' && !isspace(*endptr)))
                exit_input_error(total+1);

            ++i;
        }
        x[i].index = -1;

        predict_label = svm_predict(model,x);
        fprintf(output,"%g\n",predict_label);


        double dec_value;
        svm_predict_values(model, x, &dec_value);
        true_labels.push_back((target_label > 0)? 1: -1);
        if(labels[0] <= 0) dec_value *= -1;
        dec_values.push_back(dec_value);
    }   

    validation_function(dec_values, true_labels);

    fscore(dec_values, true_labels);
    precision(dec_values, true_labels);
    recall(dec_values, true_labels);

    free(labels);
    free(x);
}
```

Having just one of the evaluation function like `double (*validation_function)(const dvec_t&, const ivec_t&) = precision;` everything works fine and I'm having a proper output like this:

```
optimization finished, #iter = 10012
nu = 0.519566
obj = -121646.218467, rho = -59.755150
nSV = 4299, nBSV = 4010
Total nSV = 4299
Precision = 81.18% (5875/7237)
Cross Validation = 81.18%
```

However I would like to have something like:

```
optimization finished, #iter = 10012
nu = 0.519566
obj = -121646.218467, rho = -59.755150
nSV = 4299, nBSV = 4010
Total nSV = 4299
Precision = 81.18% (5875/7237)
Recall = XX.XX% (5875/7237)
Accuracy = XX.XX% (5875/7237)
Cross Validation = 81.18%
```

Is that feasible? Someone of you had similar experiences?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each of the "evaluation functions" use `printf` to print the value they compute, if you start with the original code from [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/eval/eval.cpp), it might be easier to simply call them in order before the `return validation_function(dec_values, ty);` statement in `binary_class_cross_validation`. Something like this:

```
double binary_class_cross_validation(const svm_problem *prob, const svm_parameter *param, int nr_fold)
{
    // ...

    precision(dec_values, ty);
    recall(dec_values, ty);
    accuracy(dec_values, ty);
    return validation_function(dec_values, ty);
}
```

Note that whichever function you set as the `validation_function` (by default `auc`) will compute the "Cross Validation" value that gets printed in the `main()` function of `svm-train.c` as described in [the tutorial](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/eval/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

At a glance it somewhat is not a libsvm problem, but a cpp one. Haven't run your code, but I think a simple way you may want to do is

```
double* binary_class_cross_validation(const svm_problem *prob, const svm_parameter *param, int nr_fold)
{
    ...
    double* eval = Malloc(double,3);
    eval[0] = precision(dec_values, true_labels);
    eval[1] = recall(dec_values, true_labels);
    eval[2] = accuracy(dec_values, true_labels);
    return eval;
}
```